# mongoose - how do I get the elements removed from $pull

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using $pull to pull a subdocument within an array of a document.
Don't know if it matters but in my case the subdocuments contain _id so they are indexed. 
Here are JSONs that describes the schemas:

```
user: {
  _id: String,
  items: [UserItem]
}
UserItem: {
  _id: String,
  score: Number
}
```

Now my problem is this: I am using $pull to remove certain UserItem's from a User.

```
var delta = {$pull:{}};
delta.$pull.items={};
delta.$pull.items._id = {$in: ["mongoID1", "mongoID2" ...]};
User.findOneAndUpdate(query, delta, {multi: true}, function(err, data){
    //whatever...
});
```

What i get in data here is the User object after the change, when what i wish to get is the items that were removed from the array (satellite data).
Can this be done with one call to the mongo or do I have to do 2 calls: 1 find and 1 $pull?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You really cannot do this, or at least there is nothing that is going to return the "actual" elements that were "pulled" from the array in any response, even with the newer WriteResponse objects available to the newer Bulk Operations API ( which is kind of the way forward ).

The only way you can really do this is by "knowing" the elements you are "intending" to "pull", and then comparing that to the "original" state of the document before it was modified. The basic MongoDB [`.findAndModify()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) method allows this, as do the mongoose wrappers of [`.findByIdAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) as well and [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate).

Basic usage premise:

```
var removing = [ "MongoId1", "MongoId2" ];

Model.findOneAndUpdate(
    query,
    { "$pull": { "items._id": { "$in": removing } } },
    { "new": false },
    function(err,doc) {
        var removed = doc.items.filter(function(item) {
           return removing.indexOf(item) != -1;
        });

        if ( removed.length > 0 )
           console.log(removed);
    }
);
```

Or something along those lines. You basically "turn around" the default mongoose `.findOneAndUpdate()` ( same for the other methods ) behavior and ask for the "original" document before it was modified. If the elements you asked to "pull" were present in the array then you report them, or inspect / return true or whatever.

So the mongoose methods differ from the reference implementation by returning the "new" document by default. Turn this off, and then you can "compare".

Further notes: "multi" is not a valid option here. The method modifies "one" document by definition. Also you make a statement that the array sub-documents conatain an `_id`. This is done by "mongoose" by default. But those `_id` values in the array are "not indexed" unless you specifically define an index on that field. The only default index is the "primary document" `_id`.

Comment: According to this the only way might be to do a javascript and load it to the mongo. But how do i do that from mongoose? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/load/

Comment: @TzaliMaimon No you don't need to load code to the server, and it's highly inadvisable to do so. Not sure what is not clear to you here, so perhaps you need to read the answer again. It compares the "original" content to what you asked to remove. That's how you can tell what "has" been removed.

Comment: I'll make it clear then. What you advise to do isn't practical. Since my subdocuments are indexed, it only means that I am trying to make all CRUD actions using their IDs in O(1). What you tell me to do is search in O(n) for what I removed. So Your solution was perfectly clear to me, only it is not acceptable by the demands of my question. Now for your comment: you say it is unadvisable to load code to mongo. Can you link an article on the subject or explain why? Thank you

Comment: @TzaliMaimon The document gets modified **once**. The return happens in the same wire transaction as the modification. You get the origiinal form back and what you asked to update to what the document contains before it was modified tells you what your modification actually did. Very simple.

Comment: Regarding your response, you didn't understand what I'm saying: I did not say that the update on the document happens n times. Look at your code. see the filter function? that means you go through all items in the array field of the document to search a match for the item you removed. so if I have an array of n items, it will take O(n) times to find that element in the array. It is quite "Very Simple" to put it in your words.